# Is this correct? Number of integer $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $xyz=2520$

Tags: combinatorics

The question is "How many integer triples $(x,y,z)$ satisfy $xyz = 2520$". I want to confirm whether or not this is correct, if not please point out my mistake. All replies are greatly appreciated. My solution is:

$xyz = 2520 = 2^{3}3^{2}5^{1}7^{1}$

Let $x=2^{a_1}\cdot3^{b_1}\cdot5^{c_1}\cdot7^{d_1}$

$y=2^{a_2}\cdot3^{b_2}\cdot5^{c_2}\cdot7^{d_2}$

$z=2^{a_3}\cdot3^{b_3}\cdot5^{c_3}\cdot7^{d_3}$

$\Rightarrow a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}=3$

$\Rightarrow b_{1}+b_{2}+b_{3}=2$

$\Rightarrow c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}=1$

$\Rightarrow d_{1}+d_{2}+d_{3}=1$

The number of $(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})$ which satisfy $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3} = 3$ is $\binom{3+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{5}
{2}=10$

Similarly, the number of triples that satisfy the three other equations are $\binom{4}{2}=6$,$\binom{3}{2}=3$ and $\binom{3}{2}=3$.

Thus, the total number of positive solutions $(x,y,z)=10\cdot6\cdot3\cdot3 = 540$

But if two of the numbers are negative, the equation is still satisfied, the number of solutions where two numbers are negative is $\binom{3}{2}\cdot540=3\cdot540$

So, the total number of solutions is $4\cdot540=2160$

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: It is important to note here that the order of $x,y,z$ is important and that $1$ is an acceptable value for these, in other words $(1,1,2520)$ and $(2520,1,1)$ are both acceptable and different valid arrangements that we wanted to count.  The problem becomes a bit harder if we don't allow $1$'s and/or if we explicitly want to only count cases where $x\leq y\leq z$ so that we don't repeat ourselves.